# How to stop Nautilus from creating thumbnails of specific file types?

Tags: nautilus, pdf, thumbnails

I'm trying to stop Nautilus from creating thumbnails of PDF files. In another thread on 'Ubuntu forums' someone said to open gconf-editor and disable the PDF entry in the '/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers' directory. However the only entry in that DIR is disable all. Needless to say I don't want that.

How can I disable the thumbnails for a specific file type?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thumbnails of specific file types can be disabled using dconf editor.

**Install dconf editor:**

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Or search for "dconf-tools" in Software Center and install it from there.

**How to disable thumbnails of specific file type?**

- Once installed, Hit super key (windows key) to open Unity dash and search for "dconf editor" and open it.
- Navigate to `org > gnome > desktop > thumbnailers`
- Paste the MIME type of PDF `'application/pdf'` in the value field of disable key, Like shown below.

[image]

This will prevent Nautilus from generating thumbnails of PDF's in the future but old thumbnails will be there. To solve this you'll have to clear Nautilus thumbnail cache.

- Open your home directory and Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show the hidden files and folders.
- Open `.thumbnails` and delete all the files in it. 
  **Edit for 19.10**: Open `.cache` and delete the `thumbnails` folder.
- Restart your system or kill Nautilus (`alt+f2`; `nautilus -q`) for change to take effect.

To disable thumbnails for other file types, Add there MIME type in disable list as described above. Seprate multiple types with comma. like this:

['application/pdf','image/jpeg','video/mp4']

For complete list of MIME types visit [iana.org](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html).

Comment: Is there a way to exclude (for example) all video types without writting them all ? I tried ['video/*'] but it doesn't work.

Comment: There's [no dconf-tools in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248426/what-has-replaced-dconf-tools-for-ubuntu-20-04) anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In order to stop showing thumbnails for **any video file** (because on my little HTPC it's causing high CPU usage):

First, clean the thumbnail cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

Apply the mime type list:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailers disable "['application/annodex','application/mp4','application/ogg','application/vnd.rn-realmedia','application/x-matroska','video/3gpp','video/3gpp2','video/annodex','video/divx','video/flv','video/h264','video/mp4','video/mp4v-es','video/mpeg','video/mpeg-2','video/mpeg4','video/ogg','video/ogm','video/quicktime','video/ty','video/vdo','video/vivo','video/vnd.rn-realvideo','video/vnd.vivo','video/webm','video/x-bin','video/x-cdg','video/x-divx','video/x-dv','video/x-flv','video/x-la-asf','video/x-m4v','video/x-matroska','video/x-motion-jpeg','video/x-ms-asf','video/x-ms-dvr','video/x-ms-wm','video/x-ms-wmv','video/x-msvideo','video/x-sgi-movie','video/x-tivo','video/avi','video/x-ms-asx','video/x-ms-wvx','video/x-ms-wmx']"
```

Then, just in case:

```
nautilus -q
```

I have got the mime type list from [here](http://www.codingcereal.com/2011/10/an-array-of-45-video-mime-types/).

Comment: For anyone reaching this now, org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailers.disable-all is now a key that accepts true/false.