# How do I enable thumbnails for text files in nautilus?

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, thumbnails

I used to have thumbnails for text files in Nautilus but I don't have them anymore. I'm on Ubuntu 12.10, I haven't disabled them as per [How to stop Nautilus from creating thumbnails of specific file types?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136024/how-to-stop-nautilus-from-creating-thumbnails-of-specific-file-types) and they are displayed for other file types like pdf and videos.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/7oJmyxi.png)?

Comment: Exactly. Exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/899793). As all the icons in question were all in a Ubuntu One synchronized folder, the live text preview (which works differently for text files and for other filetypes,  hence the inability of scripts to regenerate thumbnails to make thumbnails of text files) does not work because Ubuntu one uses emblems and they break the live text preview.

Answer (score 1):

To have an icon with a preview text for all the text files, follow this steps:

1. Open the *Preferences* menu in the *Edit* tab
2. Click the *Preview* tab
3. Now you will see that the first option is "Show text in icons", choice it and select *Always*

Result:

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: I have already tried that and it does not work:-/.

Comment: In this case you should check exactly the configurations that you made using `dconf` and try to disable and revert it.

Comment: Hm, I am fiddling with it but with no succes. There do not seem to be so many options related to it.  But it works with a guest account so I guess I will try some form of bisection. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Renaming my `.config/dconf` resets my settings but does not bring thumbnails. I tried to use James Henstridge's script from http://askubuntu.com/questions/199110/how-can-i-instruct-nautilus-to-pre-generate-thumbnails?rq=1 but it complains it cannot preview text/plain, which puzzles me deeply.

Comment: So it turns out to be a bug (see my answer for details).