# How to remove text from file icons?

Tags: nautilus, icons

I am fairly new to Ubuntu (Linux). I noticed when creating a .java file or .py gives me an icon, however when I start writing code it overrides the thumbnail into showing text. Is there a way to disable this silly feature ? When I installed Linux Mint on the VM I noticed I was able to accomplish this task by unchecking "Show text in icon". I know they use Namo as their file manager.

I read this thread and it did not work.  [How to stop Nautilus from creating thumbnails of specific file types?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136024/how-to-stop-nautilus-from-creating-thumbnails-of-specific-file-types)

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting for this in Nautilus (3.4 here, can't confirm if it still works on more recent revisions):

*Edit* → *Preferences* → *Preview* → Set *Show text in icons* to *Never*

[image]

Comment: thank you very much responding. I don't believe the new versions of Ubuntu contain this version of nautilus. Do you mind telling me which version your using ? Thank You

Comment: @Jesse I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: This option is now disabled in Ubuntu 14.04+.