# How to enable thumbnail preview for text files in Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 15.10, thumbnails, previews

I have many small text files, and want Nautilus to show previews in the icon thumbnail.

Left is my current situation, right is what I want.

[image: Nautilus thumbnails text preview]

How to achieve that on Ubuntu 15.10?

My current Nautilus settings: [image: Nautilus preview settings]

If an official solution is not available, workarounds/hacks are accepted too.

Comment: Tried the opposite of http://askubuntu.com/a/368252/158442?

Comment: retracted my dupe vote, since it does not *automatically* set the icons, but it might be helpful. http://askubuntu.com/questions/558846/generate-thumbnails-for-text

Comment: As my answer says, the feature has been removed. I don't know what more you expect to find out.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Nemo issue](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/954), this feature was removed in GTK itself.

GTK commit: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/gtk/gtkicontheme.c?id=aa44c0ca53b8d32c9bf3114b53ce4983ec05e86e

Reason cited by GTK:

> GtkIconTheme: Drop the code for parsing .icon files
>   Modern icon themes don't ship .icon files anyway.

Comment: I miss that, is there a work around?