# Nautilus crashes when viewing directory with .jp2

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, jpeg

Nautilus crashes whenever one tries viewing a directory containing jpeg 2000 files, I suspect because it tries to create a thumbnail and fails (I'm using 13.10, and you can probably reproduce this quite easily as well).

1. Is there a way to tell nautilus not to thumbnail certain formats?
2. Is there a known fix for this problem? There are similar bugs for very old versions of nautilus, but not any in recent years.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jasper/+bug/427100).

To disable thumbnails of .jp2, see [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136024/how-to-stop-nautilus-from-creating-thumbnails-of-specific-file-types)

Comment: What's the mime type though?

Comment: The mime type is `image/jp2`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - `file` says the mime type is octal, not jp2 :(

Comment: Octal doesn't seem to be a valid mime type?

Comment: Disabling jp2 thumbnails still causes the crash in Utopic, btw