# How to disable .txt content icon preview?

Tags: icons, text

I wish to permanently disable the process that generates a preview of any file content (specially text files) and generates an new icon for it. Sometimes my programs quickly update several files and this keep jamming the folder window during the process. I disabled evince-thumbnailer but I don't think it's what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: see the answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/136216/425087 (maybe adding something like `plain` or `text/plain` as a type )

Answer (score 0):

I did it using dconf-tools package. See:

[How to stop Nautilus from creating thumbnails of specific file types?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136024/how-to-stop-nautilus-from-creating-thumbnails-of-specific-file-types/136216#136216)

Just mark the option disable-all under thumbnailers